# Subspaces of metric spaces having prescribed dimension

Tags: geometric-measure-theory, hausdorff-dimension

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space having Hausdorff dimension $\alpha>0$ and let $0<\beta<\alpha$. Is there a metric subspace of $X$ having Hausdorff dimension $\beta$?

Comment: Thinking about a fancy way that I don't know if it could work. Take a continous $\gamma$ from [0,1] to the space of compact subsets of $X$ with the hausdorff distance. 
1. Is the hausdorff measure of $\gamma(t)$ a continous function of $t$?
2. Is there a compact subset K of X such that it ha s the same hausdorff measure?
3. Is $K$ connected to a point in the space of compact subsets?
Of course, this would yield the answer, but I have no idea if it is effective..

Comment: Welcome Nicola, nice to see you

Comment: For $X=\mathbb R^n$ the answer is positive, see e.g. [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/325532).

Comment: Hi Pietro. Skeeve: the question is about general metric spaces. Locally compact and complete could be a reasonable restriction. Euclidean space is restricting too much. Andrea: thanks for the hint.

Comment: @AndreaMarino: We'd need to look at the Hausdorff *dimension*, right?  And that is certainly not continuous with respect to Hausdorff distance.  Consider $X = [0,1]$ and $\gamma(t) = [0,t]$, so $\gamma(t)$ has Hausdorff dimension $1$ for every $t>0$ but dimension zero for $t=0$.

Comment: You are right. What about increasing sequences, in the sense of $\gamma(t) \subset \gamma(s)$ for $t<s$, and limita from the left? I am trying to thinking to limsup of compact spaces. But probably you are right, no hope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Corollary 7 in [How95], every analytic subset of a complete separable metric
space which has positive (or infinite) Hausdorff measure of dimension s contains a compact
set which has finite and positive Hausdorff measure of dimension s.

[How95] J.D. Howroyd. On dimension and on the existence of sets of finite positive
Hausdorff measure. Proc. London Math. Soc. (3), 70:581–604, 1995.

Comment: Thank you, Yuval: this completely answers my question.

Comment: Hi Nicola,    In that case the standard procedure is to upvote and officially accept the answer   See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Thanks also for this tip, Yuval: I'm new here and still learning. I hope I did it.

Comment: @NicolaArcozzi: This is an interesting paper but it does not resolve your question what is about existence of subsets of given dimension strictly less than $s=\alpha$.

Comment: @Misha. I think it does: if the dimension of $X$ is $s>\alpha$, then the $\alpha$-Hausdorff measure of $X$ is infinite, by the theorem in the paper I can find a compact subset $K$ of $X$ having finite and positive $\alpha$ measure, hence $K$ has dimension $\alpha$. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Nicola, you are right.

Comment: @NicolaArcozzi: Sorry, you are right, I did not read the statement carefully.